# What is "The Problem of Counterfactuals?"

Tags: logic

From Wikipedia:

> The PROBLEM of counterfactuals
>
> According to the material conditional analysis, a natural language
> conditional, a statement of the form ‘if P then Q’, is true whenever
> its antecedent, P, is false. Since counterfactual conditionals are
> those whose antecedents are false, this analysis would wrongly predict
> that all counterfactuals are vacuously true.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#The_problem_of_counterfactuals

Is this really a "problem?"

Consider the counterfactual conditional: "If the release valve had been working properly, the explosion would have been contained." (Maybe this is not a good example?)

We have: $ValveFailure \implies Explosion~~~$ (for logical propositions $ValveFailure$ and $Explosion$)

This implication is vacuously true if the antecdent, *ValveFailure*, is false. In that case, we cannot determine the truth value of *Explosion* since the antecedent is false. Without introducing any inconsistencies, *Explosion* could be either true or false. Other possible causes of an explosion are *not* ruled out. It seems that, in this case anyway, the material condition will suffice.

---

Another possible approach...

From propositional logic, we know that $(A\land B)\implies (\neg A \implies \neg B)$:

[image]

The original "counterfactual conditional" suggests that both $ValveFailure$ and $Explosion$ are true.

Therefore, we have: $\neg ValveFailure \implies \neg Explosion$

This looks suspiciously like our original "counterfactual conditional." What, if anything, are we to make of this?

Comment: The point is that, in terms of the Wikipedia article's analysis, if your statement is in fact a counterfactual then that means that, in reality, the release valve wasn't working properly, and the explosion wasn't contained. That means the antecedent is false, so the material conditional is vacuously true, and hence is not making a meaningful claim about "what would have happened if the antecedent had been true."

Comment: We can assume that a valve failure will result in an explosion. It was not stated that valve failure is the only possible cause of an explosion. It would not be reasonable to assume this in any  case. So, if the valve did not fail (antecedent is false), no meaningful claim can be made about there being an explosion or not.

Comment: How did you get from "If the release valve had been working properly, the explosion would have been contained." to your formula? Isn't it $ValveWorking \Rightarrow ExplosionContained$? Or, at best, reading more into it $(Explosion \wedge ValveWorking) \Rightarrow ExplosionContained$

Answer (score 2):

There are various Problems with Counterfactuals.

I will give only 2 Classes :

**Class 1 :**

(1A) If "Historical Event X" had not occurred , we would have no Poverty all over the world.
(1B) If "Historical Event X" had not occurred , we would have Poverty over the world.

Both are valid , because "Historical Event X" did occur.

(2A) If "World war 3" had occurred in 1955 , we would have no Poverty all over the world.
(2B) If "World war 3" had occurred in 1955 , we would have Poverty over the world.

Both are valid , because "World war 3" did not occur.

**Class 2 :**

(3A) If "1=3" , "42 is the answer to all queries"
(3B) If "1=3" , "42 is not the answer to all queries"

(4A) If "$4 \in \{1,2,3\}$" , "42 is the answer to all queries"
(4B) If "$4 \in \{1,2,3\}$" , "42 is not the answer to all queries"

All Counterfactuals are valid.

**With your Example :**

"If the release valve had been working properly, the explosion would have been contained."

Imagine a terrorist attack on a Petrol Station & the Security Company ( which did not secure the Petrol Station ) trying to evade responsibility : "Hey , you gave us 10,000,000 Dollars & we did our best : We put in the 100 Dollar CCTV camera to deter terrorists. When our agents went for the 2-hour lunch break , somebody broke in to throw a bomb. Now , your release valve did not work. **If the release valve had been working properly, the explosion would have been contained.** That is not out fault"

During the bombing with a release valve failure , that is vacuously true , but invalid.

During the bombing with no release valve failure , the Security Company can even claim : **"If the release valve had been not working properly, the explosion would have been contained."** which is still vacuously true + still invalid.

**Class 3 :**

I had a look at your given Article now , hence I am including a new Class. I think , "Non-monotonicity" is a Class which uniquely occurs in Counterfactuals.

Let $A:1=0$

If $ A $ , then $ Z $
If $ A \land A1 $ , then $ \lnot Z $
If $ A \land A1 \land A2 $ , then $ \lnot Z $
If $ A \land A1 \land A2 \land A3 $ , then $ Z $
If $ A \land A1 \land A2 \land A3 \land A4 $ , then $ \lnot Z $
If $ A \land A1 \land A2 \land A3 \land A4 \land A5 $ , then $ Z $

Even though we are adding more Conditions , the Conclusion is toggling.
All this because $A$ is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. If $A$ is false, then $A\implies B$ is always true (or valid) regardless of the truth value of $B$. Likewise, $A\implies \neg B$ is also then true (or valid) regardless of the truth value of $B$. This may seem counter-intuitive, but there is no inconsistency here. We will not be able, for example, to prove that $B \land \neg B$ is true. There is no need to concoct a different kind of conditional to handle such situations. The material condition is quite sufficient in these cases.

Comment: Correct : When $A$ is not true , all variations [[ "if $A$ , then $B$" , "if $A$ , then $\lnot B$" , "if $A$ , then $B \land \lnot B$" , "if $A$ , then $B \lor \lnot B$" ]] are vacuously true , which is consistent though not useful. In Mathematical Logic , when variation 3 arises , the Automatic Conclusion is that $A$ is not true.

Comment: @DanChristensen The reason it is considered a problem is simply because the material conditional represents "if P is true, then Q is true", whereas counterfactual conditionals have the form "if P was true, then Q would be true". With material conditionals, $\lnot P$ makes $P \to Q$ true, but that doesn't reasonably for counterfactuals, which are common in natural language but not truth-functional. 

For an example, contrast "If Lee Harvey Oswald didn't kill JFK, someone else did" with "If Lee Harvey Oswald didn't kill JFK, someone else would've".